# Can I talk to my friends while playing?

Tags: borderlands-2

Can I chat with my friends with the ps3 headset while playing coop with them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to communicate with my friends via the PS3 headset while playing in cooperative mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a Bluetooth or head set w/ mix. Go to your PS3 settings and be sure that they are linked. Form your group of 2-4 players and you can now talk to them.